# LocomotiveCMS and Heroku - deployment issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, locomotivecms

I followed the instructions for deploying a locomotivecms app to Heroku:

http://doc.locomotivecms.com/installation/heroku

heroku open command brings up an error page in the browser. heroku logs reveal following:

```
response => #<Excon::Response:0x00000004ee6548 @body="App not found.", @headers={"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Date"=>"Fri, 01 Jun 2012 20:10:00 GMT", "Server"=>"nginx/1.0.14", "Status"=>"404 Not Found", "Strict-Transport-Security"=>"max-age=500", "X-Runtime"=>"40", "Content-Length"=>"14", "Connection"=>"keep-alive"}, @status=404>
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Accept"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Authorization"=>"Basic OmNjYzY1ZmMyNTFkODY1MmQ2NWJhOWVkMTA1MjJjM2E2NTc4NmRiNzM=", "User-Agent"=>"heroku-rb/0.1.8", "X-Heroku-API-Version"=>"3", "X-Ruby-Version"=>"1.9.3", "X-Ruby-Platform"=>"x86_64-linux", "Host"=>"api.heroku.com:443"}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.13.4/data/cacert.pem", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"api.heroku.com", :path=>"/apps/homeschool_minder/domains", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :expects=>200, :method=>:get}
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.13.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:97:in `request'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.1.8/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.1.8/lib/heroku/api/domains.rb:27:in `get_domains'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive-heroku-0.0.1/lib/locomotive/heroku.rb:17:in `domains'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive-heroku-0.0.1/lib/locomotive/heroku/enabler.rb:21:in `enable_heroku'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:100:in `enable_hosting'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:68:in `after_configure'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:38:in `configure'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/locomotive.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:10:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-06-01T20:10:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-06-01T20:10:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-06-01T20:10:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by swapna.sony@gmail.com
2012-06-01T20:10:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 66801e9 by swapna.sony@gmail.com
2012-06-01T20:10:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-06-01T20:10:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-06-01T20:10:45+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-06-01T20:10:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 24745`
2012-06-01T20:10:58+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-01T20:10:58+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   ...loading heroku extension
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Accept"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Authorization"=>"Basic OmNjYzY1ZmMyNTFkODY1MmQ2NWJhOWVkMTA1MjJjM2E2NTc4NmRiNzM=", "User-Agent"=>"heroku-rb/0.1.8", "X-Heroku-API-Version"=>"3", "X-Ruby-Version"=>"1.9.3", "X-Ruby-Platform"=>"x86_64-linux", "Host"=>"api.heroku.com:443"}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.13.4/data/cacert.pem", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"api.heroku.com", :path=>"/apps/homeschool_minder/domains", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :expects=>200, :method=>:get}
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.1.8/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive-heroku-0.0.1/lib/locomotive/heroku/enabler.rb:21:in `enable_heroku'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.13.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:97:in `request'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.1.8/lib/heroku/api/domains.rb:27:in `get_domains'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.13.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:266:in `request_kernel': Expected(200) <=> Actual(404 Not Found) (Heroku::API::Errors::NotFound)
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   response => #<Excon::Response:0x000000044fae30 @body="App not found.", @headers={"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Date"=>"Fri, 01 Jun 2012 20:11:03 GMT", "Server"=>"nginx/1.0.14", "Status"=>"404 Not Found", "Strict-Transport-Security"=>"max-age=500", "X-Runtime"=>"39", "Content-Length"=>"14", "Connection"=>"keep-alive"}, @status=404>
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.
1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:100:in `enable_hosting'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive-heroku-0.0.1/lib/locomotive/heroku.rb:17:in `domains'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:68:in `after_configure'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/locomotive.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc7/lib/locomotive.rb:38:in `configure'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T20:11:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-06-01T20:11:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-06-01T20:11:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

What does it mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be incorrect app name in the locomotive.rb file. The app name did not match the app name on Heroku.